# find rows in table1 that are not in table2 based on comparing two columns

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables that have 3 columns. I want to compare two columns in both tables to find the rows that are in the first one but not the other. So far I am using a `LEFT JOIN` on two columns. I tested on a temp tables with junk data and the method works but my production data set has a lot of rows so I cannot validate if it actually works.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    [Timestamp] [date],
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [value] [varchar](50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE table2(
    [Timestamp] [date],
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [value] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

.

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('2017-09-10', 'a', 'one'),
('2017-01-19', 'a', 'two'),
('2016-12-07', 'a', 'three'),
('2016-11-15', 'b', 'four'),
('2016-10-19', 'b', 'five'),
('2017-07-09', 'b', 'six'),
('2016-01-31', 'c', 'seven'),
('2016-12-15', 'd', 'eight');

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('2016-12-15', 'a', 'two'),
('2016-06-20', 'b', 'four'),
('2017-04-09', 'b', 'five'),
('2016-03-03', 'b', 'six'),
('2016-03-24', 'c', 'seven'),
('2016-07-04', 'e', 'nine'),
('2016-10-24', 'f', 'ten'),
('2016-11-06', 'g', 'eleven')
```

.

```
SELECT * FROM table1

    | Timestamp  | name | value | 
    |------------|------|-------| 
    | 2017-09-10 | a    | one   | 
    | 2017-01-19 | a    | two   | 
    | 2016-12-07 | a    | three | 
    | 2016-11-15 | b    | four  | 
    | 2016-10-19 | b    | five  | 
    | 2017-07-09 | b    | six   | 
    | 2016-01-31 | c    | seven | 
    | 2016-12-15 | d    | eight | 

SELECT * FROM table2

    | Timestamp  | name | value  | 
    |------------|------|--------| 
    | 2016-12-15 | a    | two    | 
    | 2016-06-20 | b    | four   | 
    | 2017-04-09 | b    | five   | 
    | 2016-03-03 | b    | six    | 
    | 2016-03-24 | c    | seven  | 
    | 2016-07-04 | e    | nine   | 
    | 2016-10-24 | f    | ten    | 
    | 2016-11-06 | g    | eleven |
```

.

```
SELECT table1.name, table1.value, IIF(table2.Timestamp IS NULL, 'missing', 'not missing') AS 'status' FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name AND table1.value = table2.value

    | name | value | status      | 
    |------|-------|-------------| 
    | a    | one   | missing     | 
    | a    | two   | not missing | 
    | a    | three | missing     | 
    | b    | four  | not missing | 
    | b    | five  | not missing | 
    | b    | six   | not missing | 
    | c    | seven | not missing | 
    | d    | eight | missing     |
```

.

```
DROP TABLE table1
DROP TABLE table2
```

Comment: Seems fine to me. I hope in your real tables you have better column names though as using reserved words is not a good practice.

Comment: name and value both allow null. your example data doesnt have any nulls. have you tested those? does your code do what you want?

Comment: In my real data it doesn't allow `null` nor will there be any `null`s. I just threw that together quickly for the sake of the question. The code works on the smaller test tables but I don't have a reliable way to verify it works on my bigger production tables. That is why I was asking here to get verification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  You just needed to test for the right side value to be null to determine if there was no match.  For best performance you'll want to index on name & value in both tables.

```
SELECT  table1.name,
        table1.value
  FROM  table1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
    ON table1.name = table2.name
    AND table1.value = table2.value
  WHERE table2.value IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! So the way I have it will still work if I want to see all the rows and indicate if they match or don't match.